# Request Failed when Add custom headers Vue

Tags: vue.js, request, fetch

I'm doing a request with Axios but this fail when add custom headers (custom headers are required by the API).
If add the custom headers the response is:

`has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

I have seen that two requests are made:
1- firs request:
[image: first request]

2- Second request
[image: second request]

In the API are enabled CORS

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Origin, X-Requested-With, Content- 
Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method,t-id-establecimiento,bt- 
username,bt-nombre-empleado,ipaddress");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
```

My request in Vue:

```
let headers = this.getHeader()
    this.$http(`${mUrl}`,{headers})
      .then(function (resp) {
         console.log(resp.data)

      })
 .catch(function (err) {
  console.log('rerrrr' + err)
})
```

My custom header:

```
{
 'Authorization': "Bearer " + urlParams.get('token'),
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'bt-id-establecimiento': urlParams.get('bt-id-establecimiento'),
 'bt-username': urlParams.get('bt-username'),
 'bt-nombre-empleado': urlParams.get('bt-nombre-empleado'),
 'ipaddress': urlParams.get('ipaddress'),

}
```

Comment: Can you add a code snippet that shows how you enabled support for OPTIONS requests on the server for the `http://api.localhost/form/v1/form1/` endpoint? That endpoint needs to be configured to respond to OPTIONS requests with a 200 OK. Right now, that endpoint’s responding to the OPTIONS request with a 400 Bad Request error.

Answer (score -2):

When dealing with a CORS error, most of the time you do not need to modify your request headers. 99% of the time, the problem is in the backend. Make sure to allow CORS in:

- Server Configuration and
- Application

If you are using XAMPP or any Apache server, by default CORS is not enabled. Although you already allow CORS on your application, it will still be blocked by the server.

Take note: make sure to restart your server when making changes to the configuration file